# DPM transaction log backups of SQL Server partially contained databases

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017, dpm

I am trying to use `Microsoft System Center Data Protection Manager (DPM) 2016 (5.0.342.0)` to protect `SQL Server 2017 Standard CU8 (14.0.3029.16)` on `Windows Server Std 2016`.

I have a named instance with the standard built-in databases (master, msdb, model) and a couple of custom databases that were created by doing a restore from a full backup of SQL Server 2012.

I have switched the custom databases to partially contained and to database compatibility level 140.  Their Recovery Model is Full.  They are not in an Always-On Availability group, they are not configured for mirroring, they are not configured for transaction log shipping.

When I set up a DPM protection group and choose the entire instance, then configure 15-minute synchronizations along with daily Express full backups, DPM sets up Recovery Point jobs (effectively, transaction log backups) every 15 minutes for model, but my custom databases only get jobs for the daily full-database backup.

I can't find any specific error messages that seem relevant in Event logs (System or Application) on the DPM Server or the SQL Server, in the DPM logs (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Data Protection Manager\DPM\Temp) on the DPM server or the SQL Server, or in SQL Server's own error log.  I've granted both the DPM Server's domain computer account and the local account running the DPM agent (NT Service\DPMRA) a local user in the custom database with the db_owner role, but that doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Martin

Comment: Are the user databases part of Availability group or mirroring or log shipping - this way DPM skips it ?

Comment: Are the custom database in the full recovery model?

Comment: These databases are NOT part of an always-on availability group, are not configured for mirroring, are not configured for log shipping.  They both are in recovery model Full.

This is a lab environment so there are basically zero updates/inserts/deletes, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that the problem was not with all contained databases.  It was fixed by removing and re-adding the problem databases to the DPM protection group. I have no explanation.

Martin